# How to get filtered list based on common items in two lists in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to get a list filtered based on the matches of one of the properties with a property of another list. 
In below example, only the items which have common 'name' between both lists should be filtered in 1st list. Can some one tell me the most concise way of doing it?

```
class TCapability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class PCapability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Input:

```
var capability = new List<TCapability>()
{
    new TCapability() {Name="a", Id=1},
    new TCapability() {Name="b", Id=2},
    new TCapability() {Name="c", Id=3}
};

var type2Capability = new List<PCapability>()
{
    new PCapability() {Name="a", Code=100},
    new PCapability() {Name="b", Code=200},
    new PCapability() {Name="d", Code=300}
};
```

Expected Output:

```
capability =
{
    { Name="a", Id=1 },
    { Name="b", Id=2 }
}
```

Comment: What type your expected output have to be of? `TCapability`, `PCapability`, or something with strings?

Comment: did you tried?? any error??

Comment: You should make it easy for anyone to try your code. I've edited your code for that reason.

Comment: output should be of list of TCapability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = capability.Where(c => type2Capability.Any(c2 => c.Name == c2.Name));
```

Comment: I'd turn `type2Capability` into a `HashSet<string>` first so the lookups are `O(1)`, otherwise this is `O(mn)` overall, but this is a much simpler alternative to `Join` when you don't actually need the joined results.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn It did not filter the results. I still got same number of results as were there in Capability initially.

Comment: Yes. While debug it showed same results, but were eventually getting updated. So, it is working. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

you can try use [join clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) like this

```
capability = (from a in capability 
             join b in type2Capability on a.Name equals b.Name
             select a).ToList();
```

**UPDATE** on comment if type2Capability can have duplicate names

```
capability = (from a in capability 
             join b in type2Capability on a.Name equals b.Name into f
             where f.Any()
             select a).ToList();
```

Comment: In the case where `type2Capability` has duplicate `Name` properties, this will give multiple results - I'd use a `GroupJoin` (`join ... into` in query syntax?) and then discard items where the group is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists can get long then a HashSet can speed things up.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(type2Capability.Select(t => t.Name));
var res = capability.Where(c => set.Contains(c.Name));
```